# How to keep track of div number while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html

Assuming I have divs of varying sizes:

```
<div class="mydiv" style="height:500px;">
</div>
<div class="mydiv" style="height:212px;">
</div>
<div class="mydiv" style="height:58px;>
</div>
```

How can I make it such that when I scroll down, I know which # div that is currently being shown/or on top? Assume only 1 active div can exist at a time (the topmost div). Preferably using JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or if you don't want any extra dependencies from the third party libraries, you can subscribe to `$('#container').scroll(eventHandler)` event and loop through `e.target`'s children to find the one that is sitting on the top of the container.

```
$(".container").scroll(function (e) {
    var elementOnTheTop;
    $(e.target).children().each(function (index, element) {
        var $element = $(element);
        if ($element.position().top <= 0 && $element.height() > 0) {
            elementOnTheTop = $element;
        }
    });

    //elementOnTheTop is what you are looking for
});
```

**DEMO**: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BUX8D/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for something like this

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/magellan.html

there are plenty more that are similar and readily available.